# Почему винокурение?

Tags: этимология

Виноделие еще называют винокурением. Но я, как биолог, хорошо знаю процесс изготовления вина и никаким курением там и не пахнет (в прямом и переносном смысле). Почему же именно "винокурение"?

Comment: Что вино курить, что самогон гнать, все одно. А вот еще значение слова курить :  "*Курить*
арх. бедокурить, будить, прокудить,
проказить по легкомыслию,
опрометчивости, шалости. Что ты
накурил?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ВиноКУРЕНИЕ - потому что выкуривание.
Выкуриванием называется способ выгонки животных из их нор. Для этого у одного выхода норы разводят костер, дым от которого проникает в нору, животное от этого дыма бежит наружу на свежий воздух через свободный выход и попадает прямо в руки охотников (или заранее заготовленные сети). И по сей день мы используем это слово как сленг: выкурить - заставить кого-то выйти из своего убежища. 
Так, изготавливая спирт, мы заставляем выйти/перегоняем/выкуриваем спирт из, к примеру, бражки точно так же, как того несчастного зверя из его норы. В результате на выходе мы получаем так называемую выкурку, спиртной напиток. Виноград же у нас не растёт и виноДелием, соответственно не занимались.

А вот и подтверждение моей мысли:
"Как объясняет В.В.Похлебкин в книге «История водки», процесс винокурения скопирован с производства дегтя по типу оборудования и технологии. Смолу из березовых поленьев приходилось буквально «выгонять», долго и медленно."
http://h.ua/story/150039/

Comment: Не понимаю, при чем тут животные  - и как их может подтвердить Похлебкин.
Касательно производства водки - да, исходный процесс отдаленно напоминает получение дегтя. Но только тем что сырье приходится долго держать при определенной температуре, которую поддерживали с помощью дыма.

Answer (score 3):

Вином раньше называли водку и вообще всякий хмельной напиток.
Курение, таким образом, означает процесс, ныне известный как "перегонка". Причем секреты этого винокурения на Руси знали задолго до изобретений (несправедливо приписываемых Менделееву) технологий и самого перегонного куба.

Answer (score 3):

ВИНОКУРЕНИЕ, -я, ср. (устар.). Производство спирта, водки из сахаристых и крахмалистых продуктов (хлебных злаков, картофеля, свеклы). 
Одно из значений (разг.) слова «выгнать» - выкурить: «Они с трудом выкурили его из комнаты»

Answer (score 0):

Это семитский корень КРТ ОТДЕЛЯТЬ И СОЕДИНЯТЬ  у нас есть слово закортить те содинить и укороить -  урезать.